# Hosting C# project in AWS (Email notification issue)

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2

I have **hosted my web application** project in **AWS EC2**. In my project i have a **service of sending Email** once the user registered into my application. The issue is the email sending is **working fine Locally and IIS** but in **AWS** it is not working.

can anyone know how to solve this issue in AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this email belongs to a google app account, for example if you are trying to use a domain like **@myenterprise.com** you must activate the option to allow unsecure apps, this option it's available on the google app security settings section.

If you are trying to use something else like send emails from the server directly you can use **Amazon SES**, look at this answer for more information:

[Sending email using smtp gmail server from Amazon EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656925/sending-email-using-smtp-gmail-server-from-amazon-ec2-instance)

Otherwise, update your question to add more information about your issue, for example if you are using gmail or a local email server to send the emails.

Comment: Thank u Camaron am using Gmail SMTP in my code there is no error message displayed but the email is not received in UserSide It is working fine in IIS